# Is it possible to prepopulate React Native async storage with static data

Tags: reactjs, database, react-native, asyncstorage, data-storage

I am creating an app with a lot of static text, and I am looking for a way to store it in a clean way.
Is it possible to bundle an app with a prepopulated async stroage?
Or is there any clean way to store **a lot** of text in a react native app?

Comment: If there are alot of text I would recommend to do it with sqllite instead of async storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to put texts in json file and import that.

```
{
    "lotOfText1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "lotOfText2": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
}
```

```
import texts from '<path-here>/texts.json';

texts.lotOfText1
```